# Google BigQuery - How Google calculates the bill for tables copying

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to understand how Google calculates the bill for tables copying? I didn't find it in the documentation and UI doesn't contain this information as well. 
Is it whole table reading or just snapshot copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not costs for [copying tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free). The only thing you should keep in mind is the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#copy) applied for this operation.

Currently you can run 1000 copy table jobs per table and 10000 per project, per day.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how it works inside? Why could one table be copied in a second and the other one with the same amount of data copies half of hour? (they contains the same data, but one is partitioned, another one - not)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea. I suggest asking this specific question on SO and maybe a Google Engineer might help you (us) understanding this one. All I know is the basic structure of [capacitor](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format). Each value in a column is stored with its definition and repetition level which suffices to reconstruct entire rows of records. But when we add partitions this structure has to change somehow as otherwise the entire column is still scanned.

Comment: Some kinds of table copies only require updates to metadata (think of it like reference counting).

Comment: @ElliottBrossard thanks for the input! I imagine that partitioned tables work using some sort of metadata as well where partitions work like keys telling capacitor where data should be taken for each partition. Still, now we know time expected for a 'full copy' shouldn't change much between partitioned and regular tables.